# How do cells slowly degrade 5,5'-dibromo-4,4'-dichloro-indigo?

Tags: biochemistry, metabolism

5,5'-dibromo-4,4'-dichloro-indigo is the product of X-gal cleavage, often used as a reporter with B-galactosidase. I've made the (unreferenced) observation that it seems as though the blue product slowly degrades over periods of time within the cell, allowing for cells to lose their blue coloration.

**What mechanisms can explain the degradation of 5,5'-dibromo-4,4'-dichloro-indigo within cells?**

Comment: Can be 3 reasons: 1. Dilution 2. Reductive conversion to colorless [leuco-indigo](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/summary/summary.cgi?cid=23035) 3. Metabolic decay: I suspect the metabolism would be similar to that of purines

Comment: ^ that was purely speculation

Comment: Indigo compounds are so damn insoluble I don't know if you can get it into an enzyme easily. I've made indigo ( not the x-gal indigo in the question, but same core structure ) just for fun while my boss isn't watching, and I haven't found any solvent that will dissolve it. But maybe glutathione can slowly reduce it. When I reduce the indigo I make, I use sodium dithionate and boiling water. GSH wouldn't be as powerful, but you don't need it to work as quickly. More pure speculation.